# Duplicate data from looped through form_for select box with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

What is the best way to clone the rendered html of a rails loop and render it in a different location on the page.

I have this erb code:

```
<%= form_for @order do |f|%>

    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <%= f.fields_for :units, @order.units.build do |ff| %>
            <%= ff.select :quantity, (0..@unit_sizes.quantity), {class: "quantity_for_total"} %>
        <%end%>
    </div>

<%end%>
```

And further down the page I want to render each of the selected items, but not in a select box.

I have tried a ton of different jQuery, but can't seem to get it right, and my searching keeps leading me astray.

Answer (score 0):

This should "do" it

```
var str = "<ul>";
Array.prototype.forEach.call( document.querySelector(".col-xs-6 > 

select").children, function(opt){
str += "<li>" + opt.value + "</li>";
});
str += "</ul>";

document.querySelector(".newLocation").innerHTML = str;
```